# error when install php5 in Ubuntu : gd build test failed.Please check the config.log for details

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I want build php5.5.38 on my computer for work, when run the command

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/etc --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www --with-fpm-group=www --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-iconv-dir --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/freetype --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-xml --disable-rpath --enable-bcmath --enable-shmop --enable-sysvsem --enable-inline-optimization --with-curl --enable-mbregex --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --enable-ftp --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-openssl --with-mhash --enable-pcntl --enable-sockets --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip --enable-soap --with-gettext --disable-fileinfo
```

get report

> configure: error: GD build test failed. Please check the config.log for details.

the way I had tried:

- install gd on ubuntu with `apt-get install php5-gd`,such as this command to install gd library.can't resolve.
- download source code of gd,brew it.and the params `--with-gd` change to `--with-gd=/usr/local/gd`.can't resolve too.

I find a paper write

> this error occures because the linker (ld) cannot find the jpeg library. You can fix this problem by editing the config.nice file inside the php directory and adding LDFLAGS='-L/path/to/lib'.

Follow this way,I can't resolve yet.

I have downloaded source code of php with version 5.5, 5.6, 5,3; every of them with params `--with-gd` can't run `./configure` success.and I had rebuild different version package a lot of times. If had no response, I'm ready to re-install `make`, thx!

Comment: Continue to use the packaged version.

Comment: This is extremely confusing. You appear to wildly mix completely separate aspects. First question: _why_ do you want to install a totally outdated version? That is a huge security risk. Second: do you really need to _build_ it? Are there no packages available via the usual package repositories? Third: if you _really_ need to build that, install the gd lib along with its development package.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to mix packaged version with self-compiled version. You should use either one other other. If you're not sure, stick with the packaged version.

Comment: the reason of use different version is: wish to exclude the compatibility issues. I don't want use outdated version too, but my boss think more old version had more stable, and keep the environment of development same to online.before build other version, I have removed all file before install.because I can't confirm the place cause the problem,so I only try every thing I had learned. thx all.@Ipor Sircer@arkascha@Simba